# Redis Connection Exception when used as a Session manager for Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, redis, tomcat7

I have a redis running on a remote server and another web app is able to connect to it withou any issues. I am using redis as a session storage and when I try to connect multiple tomcat instance it throws me the error mentioned below:-

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:22)
    at com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionManager.acquireConnection(RedisSessionManager.java:111)
    at com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionManager.loadSessionFromRedis(RedisSessionManager.java:391)
    at com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionManager.findSession(RedisSessionManager.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2865)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2316)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.updateAccessedSessionAttributes(ServletRequestAttributes.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes.requestCompleted(AbstractRequestAttributes.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:954)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.tcs.com.security.filter.SecurityInterceptor.doFilter(SecurityInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionHandlerValve.invoke(RedisSessionHandlerValve.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:134)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:69)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1665)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool$JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisPool.java:72)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:20)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:129)
    ... 38 more
```

I am not able to understand the problem. I am using [tomcat-redis-session-manager](https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager)
which works great with one instance of the web application but as I move to more than one I get the above error. Please suggest how to get along with this ?

Comment: Is it valid to use a 5 digit port number on mac like 27017 ?? For Redis?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually the problem was solved by configuring a conf file for the redis. I added some appropriate parameters for this and also added around 5 clients and it started . :)

Comment: would you mind clarifying what "appropriate parameters" were added/updated? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a limit on number of connections somewhere. Check both your client and server limit settings to open file handles.